# VBA: How to download a .png file where URL directs to folder on computer

Tags: html, vba, excel, save

I created an html file that I upload in the Internet Explorer using VBA. It opens an image that I would like to save. However the URL starts with file:///.....my_file.html and therefore I cannot call for it with VBA to automatically save it to my home drive.
Is there any way to save the image without having to click on it and select "save image as"?
Help greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is the image being loaded from in your HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt your code, changing the `/` to `\` and removing the `file:///` from the filepath. Most probably something like this will work, as far as you are not downloading, but simply copying:

```
Sub Copy_One_File()

    Dim inputString As String

    inputString = "file:///C:/Users/Ron/SourceFolder/Test.png"
    inputString = Replace(inputString, "file:///", "")
    inputString = Replace(inputString, "/", "\")
    FileCopy inputString, "C:\Users\Ron\DestFolder\Test.png"

End Sub
```

Read here more for copying and pasting files:
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help, it keeps telling me, that the path can't be found.
Also if I click on the properties of the image it is not a .png but a .html still. Only if I manually save it by right clicking it and choosing "Save picture as" I get to select .png